# xCode error:- Cannot assign value of type 'URL?' to type 'UIImage?'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimage

I am attempting to pull an image url from Firebase Users profile.
When I call:-

```
@IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView?

profileImage?.image = Auth.auth().currentUser?.photoURL
```

I get the following error appear:-

```
Cannot assign value of type 'URL?' to type 'UIImage?'
```

I try to use the fixes that xcode provides but these only lead to further issues.

When I print:-

```
print(Auth.auth().currentUser?.photoURL as Any)
```

I get the following output, so I know there is an image there.

```
Optional(https://graph.facebook.com/10X60X70X35X101X5/picture)
```

How am I able to pull this image in, or is it possible to convert it to a string so I am able to use it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can not place a url in the image Use this to fetch the image from the url https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

Comment: Get Data Object from url, convert Data Object to Image and then assign to UIImageView

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the image and then set the imageView's image to the downloaded image. You can do this using URLSession's dataTask:

```
// Playground code
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))

let session = URLSession.shared
let url = URL(string: "http://via.placeholder.com/400x400")!

_ = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

    guard error == nil else {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    guard let data = data else {
        print("[DEBUG] - No data returned")
        return
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
    }

}.resume()

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = imageView
```

Or you can use a library such as [KingFisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) to handle it for you, then you just call it like so:

```
let url = URL(string: "url_of_your_image")
imageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign url to image , use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to download it asynchronously to not block main thread

```
if let url = Auth.auth().currentUser?.photoURL {

  self.profImageV.sd_setImage(with: url , placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "edit2.png"))

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very clear, you're trying to assign a `URL?` type to `UIImage?` type. Since it's a `URL?` you should first unwrap it, and download the image with this url. When you have your `UIimage` then you can assign it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are converting `URL` type to `UIImage` type, that is not possible. You need to download image from url and set in an image view or wherever you want to use.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

                if let url = URL(string: <#imageUrl#>) {

                    do {
                        let imgData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                        if let image = UIImage(data: imgData) {

                            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                                self.imageView.image = image
                            }
                        }

                    } catch {
                        debugPrint("From catch block: Image could not be downloaded !!")
                    }
                }
            }
```